# Typescript type inference in a generalized "promisify" function

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-typings

## Context

Recently I was working on "promisification" of a third-party library. Basically, the library is full of NodeJS async style functions (that use callback as a last argument). I.e. the functions which have signatures similar to this one:

`function foo(arg1: string, arg2: number, ..., callback: (error, result) => void): void`

I tried to write a function would reduce the code for wrapping the original functions and make them into `Promise<T>` returning ones:

```
function cb<TResult>(
  resolve: (res: TResult) => void,
  reject: (err: any) => void
): (actualError, actualResult) => void {

  return (error, result) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(result);
}
```

Then to promisify the methods, I'd write code like that:

```
patchUserMetadata(userId: string, userMetadata: any): Promise<a0.Auth0UserProfile> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    this.wrapped.patchUserMetadata(userId, userMetadata, cb(resolve, reject)));
}

linkUser(userId: string, secondaryUserToken: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    this.wrapped.linkUser(userId, secondaryUserToken, cb(resolve, reject)));
}

// ... and so on, and on, and on...
```

---

As you can easily see, I'm still not very familiar with TypeScript and basically was trying to reinvent a wheel. My wheel ended up being a hexagon and I kept writing too much wrapping code by hand...

Someone who reviewed my code pointed out that I can use **`js-promisify`** to achieve similar result at lower cost. The library defines a helper that does the job:

```
module.exports = function (fun, args, self) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    args.push(function (err, data) {
      err && reject(err);
      resolve(data);
    })
    fun.apply(self, args);
  });
};
```

---

Since I'm dealing with TypeScript rather than JavaScript, I went further and did a bit of research. This is how I ended up picking **`typed-promisify`** and the code now looked like this:

```
patchUserMetadata = promisify(this.wrapped.patchUserMetadata);

linkUser = promisify(this.wrapped.linkUser);
```

MUCH neater, huh?

## Getting closer

I was wondering how exactly does this `promisify` function work? I looked at the source code and found a solution which works similar to `js-promisify`'s one:

```
export function promisify<T>(f: (cb: (err: any, res: T) => void) => void, thisContext?: any): () => Promise<T>;
export function promisify<A, T>(f: (arg: A, cb: (err: any, res: T) => void) => void, thisContext?: any): (arg: A) => Promise<T>;
export function promisify<A, A2, T>(f: (arg: A, arg2: A2, cb: (err: any, res: T) => void) => void, thisContext?: any): (arg: A, arg2: A2) => Promise<T>;
// ...more overloads

export function promisify(f: any, thisContext?: any) {
  return function () {
    let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      args.push((err: any, result: any) => err !== null ? reject(err) : resolve(result));
      f.apply(thisContext, args);
    });
  }
}
```

## Question

If you look at the `promisify` closely, you can see that this solution is not really generalized. Meaning, if I needed to promisify a function with 10+ parameters, there wouldn't be a matching overload for it. The implementation would still work fine, however the type information would get lost in this case.

**Is there a way in TypeScript to infer the precise function type (or signature, or count and types of parameters) without defining all those nasty overloads upfront?**

I'm looking for something like this [obviously, pseudocode]:

```
export function promisify<...[TArgs], T>(
  f: (...allArgsButLastTwo: [TArgs],
  cb: (err: any, res: T) => void) => void,
  thisContext?: any
): (...[TArgs]) => Promise<T>;

export function promisify(
  ...allArgsButLastTwo: any[],
  f: any,
  thisContext?: any
) {
  return function () {
    let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      args.push((err: any, result: any) => err !== null ? reject(err) : resolve(result));
      f.apply(thisContext, args);
    });
  }
}
```

I have a feeling that what I'm looking for is *not* achievable and that's why long overload list was a last resort/compromise solution the author had to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 2.5, there's currently no way of doing this in TypeScript until this gets resolved:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453

It has been on the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) for a while, under Variadic Types.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for referencing the TS issue and the roadmap Filipe!!

Comment: there is a way nowadays to convert a type with callback based methods to promises based ?

Answer (score 1):

Since variadic types are now [supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) (TS 4.0+), we can write

```
type callback<P, Q> = (error: P, response: Q) => void;
const promisify =
  <T extends readonly unknown[], U, V>(
    f: (...fargs: [...T, callback<U, V>]) => void
  ) =>
  (...args: T) =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
      const callback: callback<U, V> = (err, response) => {
        if (err) rej(err);
        res(response);
      };
      f(...args, callback);
    });
```

Now, `promisify` won't always work when applied to overloaded functions. Example: The following gives an `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.` error at `'utf8'` .

```
const pmifyRead = promisify(fs.readFile); 
pmifyRead('/Users/joe/test.txt', 'utf8').then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

But, `fs.readFile` can take in two arguments before its callback argument! Unfortunately, this function has 4 overloads, and the one chosen when binding to `promisify` is the bottommost overload: The overload that only takes in `path` and `callback`.
If I can delay the type inference until the promisifed function is invoked, then everything should work. But, type is already inferred when promisified. Grateful for anyone who has a solution.